# automatically add datasource to standalone.xml in jboss as 7.1.1 on deploying ear application using entity bean

Tags: linux, jboss7.x, jsch

My JBOSS server (version 7.1.1 Final) is running in linux server. One of my ear application is deployed using jbosscli.sh by connecting to the vm using jsch. My application has an ejb (3.0) module containing entity beans. How to add datasource to the standalone.xml of jboss running on the same vm automatically...before application is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are publishing your deployment to the JBOSS server. I am using APACHE ANT build to delpoy my application into the JBoss server. In the build.xml i am sking it to edit the standalone.xml datasource subsystem as below where it picks the required properties of the datasource from a property file.

```
    <!-- TX Data Source Settings -->
    <replace file="${jboss.configuration}/standalone.xml" token="tx-connection-url&gt;tx.datasource.connection.url" value="connection-url&gt;${tx.datasource.connection.url}" />
    <replace file="${jboss.configuration}/standalone.xml" token="tx-user-name&gt;tx.datasource.username" value="user-name&gt;${tx.datasource.username}" />
    <replace file="${jboss.configuration}/standalone.xml" token="tx-password&gt;tx.datasource.password" value="password&gt;${tx.datasource.password}" />

    <!--No TX Data Source Settings -->
    <replace file="${jboss.configuration}/standalone.xml" token="no-tx-connection-url&gt;no.tx.datasource.connection.url" value="connection-url&gt;${no.tx.datasource.connection.url}" />
    <replace file="${jboss.configuration}/standalone.xml" token="no-tx-user-name&gt;no.tx.datasource.username" value="user-name&gt;${no.tx.datasource.username}" />
    <replace file="${jboss.configuration}/standalone.xml" token="no-tx-password&gt;no.tx.datasource.password" value="password&gt;${no.tx.datasource.password}" />
```